# Converting .py to .exe - no os module

Tags: python, module, operating-system, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I tried to convert my .py file to .exe with pyinstaller and cx_Freeze but in both cases it says `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'`. I have installed os and I am testing the .exe file on same PC as .py file. I do not think any code is relevant but if it is let me know and I will update it.
I also included os under packages while using cx_Freeze.
EDIT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module
File "C:\path\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line 7, in <module>
import os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'os'
```

I also get this when converting with cx_Freeze:

```
:208: SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?
if setting is None or setting is '':
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are still using `cx_freeze` under build_exe_options do not include the os as a package.

Comment: I forgot to tell that in my question sorry, but yes I included it.

Comment: I updated my question you can find it there.

Comment: can you just try converting WITHOUT the os, I have a doubt if system packages such as os are needed

Comment: regarding that warning, you can actually ignore it, its just fine.

Comment: did u try without the os package

Comment: So when I tried without os package it still did not work. But when I reinstalled Python and all the packages it works. I do not know what the problem was but I have solved it. Thank you all for your help.